# Delphi - TCameraComponent won't find flash

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, tablet-pc

I'm using Delphi 10.0 Seattle and trying to use the rear cameras's light on a Lenovo Thinkpad tablet running Windows 10 Pro. I am using `TCameraComponent`.

I tried using `CameraComponent.TorchMode := TTorchMode.ModeOn` from `FMX.Media`, but it raises an exception saying that the device has no torch.

Anyone know why this happens, and if there is some way to access this light/flash?

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: Did you check `TCameraComponent.HasTorch` first? That will stop the exception. Are you sure your tablet has a torch and not just a flash? They're not the same thing. There's are separate properties for `HasFlash` and `FlashMode`. (I can see why a phone would have a torch (so you could use it like a flashlight), but I fail to see why a Thinkpad-sized tablet (laptop) would have one.) Does your tablet have a Lenovo utility to turn on the torch?

Comment: I just checked the FMX source code in Delphi 10.0 Seattle and it does not implement **either** Flash or Torch functionality *at all* on Windows.  It is only implemented on OSX, iOS, and Android.

Comment: FlashMode didn't work as well and I didn't look for a flashlight like application in it.

Comment: Well, yeah.  Like I said, FMX does not implement Flash or Torch on Windows.  You will have to resort to using Windows-specific APIs instead to access any OS-level light/torch functionality.  There are APIs in .NET for that, so hopefully there are corresponding Win32 APIs as well.

Comment: Something like Windows Image Acquisition?  I took a look at it, but haven't figured it ou how to use it

Comment: @Remy: It appears you have an answer to this question. You should post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FMX in Delphi 10.0 Seattle does not implement **either** Flash or Torch functionality *at all* on Windows.  It is only implemented on OSX, iOS, and Android.

You will have to resort to using Windows-specific APIs, or even manufacturer-specific APIs, to access light/torch functionality.  For example, there are [`FlashControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.devices.flashcontrol.aspx) and [`TorchControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn279077) classes in the Windows UWP API.